# Elasticsearch options in Wagtail

Tags: elasticsearch, wagtail

Wagtail documentation reference for setting up the Elasticsearch index says:

> Other than BACKEND, the keys are optional and default to the values
> shown. Any defined key in `OPTIONS` is passed directly to the
> Elasticsearch constructor as a case-sensitive keyword argument (for
> example `'max_retries': 1`).

Where is the reference for what keys can be set in the `OPTIONS`?

```py
WAGTAILSEARCH_BACKENDS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'wagtail.search.backends.elasticsearch5',
        'URLS': ['http://localhost:9200'],
        'INDEX': 'wagtail',
        'TIMEOUT': 5,
        'OPTIONS': {
           # what keys can be set here?
        },
        'INDEX_SETTINGS': {},
    }
}
```